# How do I control visibility to field in my Java classes?

Tags: java, oop

How can I differentially control access to members of any class? Let's say I have three classes:-

```
Class A
{
int a;
int b;
}

Class B
{
Access to only 'a' and not 'b'
}

Class C
{
Access to only 'b' and not 'a'
}
```

Comment: you never heard about: protected, private and public?

Comment: @BookOfZeus: How will he achieve *differential* access using *access specifiers* ? I believe there is no need for such an hierarchy in any good design but Since your response I am curious to know How would you achieve this using access specifiers.

Comment: I misread the question, you are right

Comment: I want to achieve this in C# and Java both.

Comment: @Gurpreet: Why are you writing in both C# and Java at the same time? Also you didn't answer my first question: Why?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use aspect-oriented programming.  You can check to see the accessing package or class and prohibit access.

AspectJ can be used to enforce that classes in the persistence tier are not accessed in the web tier, only from the service tier.    Here's an example:

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/03/28/architectural-enforcement-with-aid-of-aspectj/

Comment: For C#, PostSharp has similar aspects that can control visibility, see http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Architectural-Validation.aspx for examples of ComponentInternal, InternalImplements, and Internal. If those don't fit your needs, you can probably write one that does.

Answer (score 1):

Interface time:

```
interface IHaveA { int a {get;set;} }
interface IHaveB { int b {get;set;} }

Class A : IHaveA, IHaveB
{
  public int a {get;set;}
  public int b {get; set;}
}

Class B
{
  IHaveA _iHaveA;

  C(IHaveA iHaveA)
  {
    _iHaveA = iHaveA;
  }
}

Class C
{
  IHaveB _iHaveB;

  C(IHaveB iHaveB)
  {
    _iHaveB = iHaveB;
  }
}
```

Then new up B and C like this:

```
static Main()
{
   A a = new A();
   B b = new B(a);
   C c = new C(a);
}
```

Comment: In this design if class B also has 'IHaveB _iHaveB' then class B can access both 'a' and 'b'. Cant it be strongly controlled?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh maybe you should explain what is it that you are trying to accomplish if Class B needs IHaveB then why don't you want it to access B?!!! sounds weird to me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really crude idea.

1. Have A have a function to take an observer derived from B, and another function to take an observer derived from A.

   ```
   class A
   {
       int a;
       int b;
       void getAObserver(B bInstance);
       void getBObserver(C cInstance);
   }
   ```
2. Then have A can call functions such as aWasUpdated or bWasUpdated on the instances make the member a and b sort of psuedo public to the specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

A really crude way of implementing this would be

```
Class A {
private int a ;
private int b ;

public int getA( Object obj) throws userDefinedIllegalAccessException {
   //check if obj isInstance of B
   // If yes return a 
   // else throw userDefinedIllegalAccessException
}
public int getB( Object obj) throws userDefinedIllegalAccessException {
   //check if obj isInstance of c
   // If yes return b 
   // else throw userDefinedIllegalAccessException
}

}

class B {

public void checkAccessValue() {
    try{
        A objA = new A()  ;
        System.out.println(objA.getA(this) ;
        System.out.println(objA.getB(this) ; 
    }
    catch(userDefinedIllegalAccessException  udException){
    } 
}
} 

class C {

public void checkAccessValue() {
    try{
        A objA = new A()  ;
        System.out.println(objA.getA(this) ;
        System.out.println(objA.getB(this) ; 
    }
    catch(userDefinedIllegalAccessException  udException){
    } 
}
}
```